# Microsoft DevOps: build triggering vs release

Tags: azure-devops, build-pipeline, release-management

I have this setup:

1. Build 1 builds and trigger Release 1 when finished
2. Build 2 is triggered by Build 1 and release Release 2

If I have one parallel job, can I be sure that:

- Release 1 is always run before the Build 2 is triggered?

I have tested this, and it does the above, but I can't find any documentation on the flow anywhere.

I need to release Release 1 before build 2 starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not trigger Build 2 automatically from Build 1. Instead add a last step to Release 1 to queue Build 2. There are a few ways to do it, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52821204/how-to-queue-build-pipeline-as-task-from-release-pipeline